# Why I can't set a specific address for my QTcpServer?

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I just want to setup my QTcpServer with a specific address. I have tried it with this code but it does not work...

```
  server.listen(QHostAddress::setAddress("127.0.0.1"),8888);
```

This is the Error:

```
Cannot call member function 'bool QHostAddress::setAddress(const QString&)' without object 
server.listen(QHostAddress::setAddress("127.0.0.1"),8888);
                                                 ^
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Cannot call member function 'bool QHostAddress::setAddress(const QString&)' without object
```

That error tells you that setAddress is not a static method, you have to call it on an object:

```
QHostAddress adr;
adr.setAddress("...");
```

In your case you can just use the QHostAddress constructor with a string parameter:

```
server.listen(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"),8888);
```